# Как найти последнюю запятую с помощью регулярного выражения?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Исходный текст:

> a,a,a,a

http://regexr.com/3epef

Нерабочий вариант:

```
/\,$/
```

И этот тоже нерабочий:

```
/,$/
```

Но что странно, находит последний символ "a". С запятой так не получается:

```
/a$/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Квантификатор `*` достаточно жаден, что бы захватить все символы до последнего встреченного символа идущего после него. Поэтому выражение совсем простое:

```
/.*,/
```

Правда вы не указали, что делать дальше с обнаруженной запятой, например можем ее захватить в группу `.*(,)`. Если же требуется посчитать запятую как все совпадение - то можно применить явное указание на точку начала совпадения (`\K`), т.е. `.*\K,`.

[Пример на regexp101.com](https://regex101.com/r/n7bmlo/1)

Что касается вашей попытки, символ `$` означает конец строки, выражение `a$` означает такую букву `a` после которой нет ни единого символа. `,$` соответственно ожидает запятую самой последней, однако после нее стоит еще `a` поэтому выражение не подходит

Comment: На том же regexr.com Ваше выражение нашло всё, кроме последней запятой.

Comment: @ModaL Разумеется, вы же не сказали, что означает "Найти запятую". Полным совпадением выражения является все до запятой и она сама.  Но саму запятую мы можем взять в круглые скобки и она будет захвачена в группу 1. Если же вы хотите что бы полным совпадением всего выражения была только запятая, то надо указать точку с которой считать совпадение `.*\K,`

Comment: можете просто на regexr написать выражение, чтобы выделило голубым фоном последнюю запятую? Если не затруднит.

Comment: @ModaL `.*\K,` https://regex101.com/r/EcLAF6/1 и чем вас зеленый не устроил

Comment: всё прекрасно. Спасибо большое за помощь :)

Answer (score 1):

Может быть, сделать так:

```
(,)([^,]*$)
```

Comment: Почти. Но Ваше выражение захватило последнюю запятую и всё что после.